# There's a bug when pressing on the textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this box when trying to press on the textformfield, it's rarely to happened by it look like a bug and it sticks to the screen even if I navigate to a different screen until I restart the app it disappears, did anyone faced something like this ?

[image]

Comment: on emulator test?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no real IOS device

Comment: This will appear while long press on text field

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh yes how to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

This comes due to long press over text field,

If you want to avoid this you have to pass `enableInteractiveSelection: false` which avoids copy and paste and other interaction from user